# Is there a way to solve this equation without inverting the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I have a matrix **A** and wish to solve the equation **Ax=b** such that **b** is a vector filled with the same constant B. The value of B is unimportant, thus for any solution **x** and any constant **C**, **Cx** is also a solution. For my purposes I am interested in the solution normed to 1 but it is sufficient to find any one nonzero solution.

Of course inverting **A** and multiplying the inverse with a constant vector **b** produces such a solution, but in my case **A** is large and I was wondering if there was a more suitable way of solving the equation since **b** has such a unique structure.

Can this be solved without inverting A?

Comment: The four asterisks are confusing here. By A****x=b, do you mean $Ax = b$, or something different?

Comment: How can $\mathbf{C x}$ be a solution? $\mathbf{A (C x)} = \mathbf{C b}$ if $\mathbf{x}$ is a solution.

Comment: In general, one solves linear systems by Gaussian elimination or some variant thereof, not by inverting the matrix and multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the question now. It is asking if there is a "nice" way to find all $\mathbf{x}$ for some matrix $A$ such that $A \mathbf{x}$ results in a vector whose entries are all the same.

Unfortunately, the answer is no. There are two cases here:

1. The resulting vector is all zeroes. Then we must solve $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.
2. If the resulting vector $\mathbf{b}$ is filled with non-zero values $B$, then the question reduces to finding the solution $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1}$, because $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} \iff A (\mathbf{x}/B) = \mathbf{1}$. So the only solutions to the equation in this case are vectors of the form $B\mathbf{u}$, where $A \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{1}$.

In general, there is no "special" way to solve $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ for any value of $\mathbf{b}$. As outlined above, what you want is equivalent to solving this equation for either $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{1}$ or $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}$.